# Перенос домена с Samba на AD windows 2008R2

Tags: samba, active-directory

вопрос, как перенести 20-30 юзеров из самбы в AD под Windows 2008R2 сервером?? в идеале еще перенести права,  но это имхо мелочи, можно будет настроить уже в самой AD

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [Active Directory Migration Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17918) для переноса пользователей из Samba в Active Directory. При этом нужно учесть, что

- пароль администратора должен быть одинаковым для везде (и Samba, AD),
- на рабочих станциях в разделе Advanced/DNS, TCP/IP settings, опция DNS suffix for this connection должна быть пустой,
- пароли пользователей не переносятся и должны быть сброшены,
- брэндмауэр на рабочих станциях должен быть отключен,

ADMT имеет возможность тестирования, и эту возможность можно использовать для устранения возникающих еще перед началом миграции ошибок.

Comment: 2008R2 ругаеццо)) пишет: несовместимо со мной! не буду ниче ставить!

Answer (score 0):

Если не этой утилитой, то каким образом перенесли домен?Очень интересует корректный перенос пользователей, чтобы профили не слетели (SID, UID,...) на рабочих компах (пароли не интересуют).

Как раз для меня этот вопрос сейчас очень актуальный.